# Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type when trying to send request body in text/plain

Tags: spring, jsr

I have an API which accepts both json and text as request body.

```
@Path("submitObjects")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public List<APIResult> submitMultiObjects(@DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam(("suppressWarnings"))Boolean suppressWarnings,List<MyObject> objects) {

// API logic

}

class MyObject{
   private String name;
   private String description;
   // and getters and setters
}
```

When I hit the API with request body in JSON it works fine.

```
[{
    "name": "name1",
    "description": "description1"
},{
    "name": "name2",
    "description": "description2"
}]
```

success for above request body

But when I pass request body in plain text it fails with error code 415 - Unsupported media type

```
name=name1
description=description1
```

failed for above request body

```
name=name1
description=description1
name=name2
description=description2
```

failed for above request body

**I wanted to know how we can pass list of objects in plain/ text format.**

For below API where I am using MyObject instead of List

```
@Path("submitObject")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public List<APIResult> submitObject(@DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam(("suppressWarnings"))Boolean suppressWarnings,MyObject object) {

// API logic

}
```

```
name=name1
description=description1
```

above request body works fine.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: it is rest api. I made POST request to url localhost:8000/submitObjects with the above mentioned request body. My server is running on port 8000.

Comment: What do you send as content-type header?

Comment: I used - 'Content-Type: text/plain'

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8000/submitObjects' 
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' 
--data-raw 'name=name1
description=description1
'

Comment: what is the use case to use plaintext for a list of objects, if it can be achieved with json?

Comment: some clients requires plain text format. Let's just say that it is mandatory.